# How an application can give suggestions based on some constraints

Tags: java, mysql, spring, artificial-intelligence

I'm new to AI. We need to develop a web application based on java & spring boot which can generate suggestion based on some constraints.

There is an organization having branches all over a country. Employees of one branch can be transferred to other branches after a certain interval of time. For example, there is an organization XYZ having four offices, A, B, C, D. Employee e1 is working in office A. After 1 year he/she is eligible for working in other offices B, C, D.

We have to develop a web app which can suggest for employee e1, that where he/she can go among three offices. Similarly, if office B has 5 vacant posts for software engineers, then how it can be filled with the employees working in other offices, A, C, D. That is, the application could suggest of most appropriate employees who can transfer from offices A, C, D to office B.

I'm unable to understand where to start and how to start? Should we include our suggestion logic in Java or should we just manipulate it using MySQL database queries like join, timestampdiff, etc? Should we throw suggestion simply on MySQL queries or retrieve data from the database and then build the logic in java to generate proper suggestion.

Comment: We can't solve your problem for you, that is what your job is paying you to do. What we can do is help in cases where you've tried X and Y but ended up with Z. This is way too broad of a question.

Comment: I'm not getting any payment for this. I'm a student show this problem on a website thinking to develop this as personal project

Comment: I understand, but your question is still too broad. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I understand it. Thanks for suggesting. I will remember next time while asking any question